# Getting value of type 'text' from mySQL database

Tags: mysql, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I am new to PHP and mySQL and this is a section of my program, but what happens is that it doesn't return the value of the column 'Text' from the database, rather, it says 'Undefined index 'Text''. I am 100% sure that it exists in the database. Can someone please help me?

```
$method_get_article = "SELECT TEXT FROM ARTICLE WHERE UID = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
$get_article = mysql_query($method_get_article, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
$article = mysql_fetch_array($get_article);**strong text**
$text = $article['Text'];
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_article);
//$text = $row['Text'];
echo $text;
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: dont use reserved words for fields BUT if you must use ` quotes around them

Comment: perform a `var_dump()` on `$article` and see what it produces.

Comment: try `$text = $article['TEXT'];`

Comment: var_dump($article); to double check

Comment: @Waygood Although you are right, `TEXT` does not strictly need backticks, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html (or any other version of the manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explains the problem very clearly : **'Undefined index 'Text'**

In the beginning you write:

```
$method_get_article = "SELECT TEXT FROM ARTICLE WHERE UID = '$user_id' LIMIT 1";
```

which means you select the column called "TEXT", and then later you write:

```
$text = $article['Text'];
```

which gets the column called "Text".

Change them so that they are identical.